# Bash tab completion colors differ from ls colors

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, ls, colors

I have `LS_COLORS` and `LSCOLORS` both defined, but for some reason, I'm being shown different colors when I use `ls` versus when I tab complete in `bash`.
I'm on MacOS.

[image]
[image]

I have these lines in my `.bashrc`

```
 bind 'set colored-stats on'
 export LSCOLORS=exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
 export LS_COLORS='di=34:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=30;41:sg=30;46:tw=30;42:ow=30;43'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out through random trying.
`bind 'set colored-stats on'` needs to appear after `LS_COLORS` is defined.